# VideoView unable to play video

Tags: android

I'm trying to play a video using video view I have a static video URL.I'm unable to play the video I get these 2 errors:

```
03-12 11:24:50.779 25718-26238/com.video E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)
03-12 11:24:50.821 25718-26065/com.video E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147479552)
```

the below URL is changed right now but I use the other 1 which is working
My compile SDK v is 28 min SDK is 16 and target SDK is 28.
[Logcat error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6Jh0.png)

```
      videoBackground = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoViewSplash);
                videoBackground.setOnErrorListener((mp, what, extra) -> false);
                String urll = "https://xxxxx-xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx/xxxx/540x960.mp4";
                videoBackground.setVideoPath(urll);
                videoBackground.setOnCompletionListener(mp -> videoBackground.seekTo(0));
                videoBackground.start();
```

Comment: Use ExoPlayer. Link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=noeSDcsHmdI&list=PLTZjfI9L19yztCS6kse-oirsoKIcFo2M2

Comment: VideoView is able to play only certain video formats and encodings. Make sure that video is in one of those formats

Answer (score 0):

Change your videoview functionlity with this

```
   String urll = "https://xxxxx-xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx/xxxx/540x960.mp4";
  videoBackground.setVideoPath(urll);
  videoBackground.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    videoBackground.start();
                    }
   });
```

Comment: @SyedFuzailByhaqi whats the error you are getting ?

Comment: same 
03-12 11:24:50.779 25718-26238/com.video E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)
03-12 11:24:50.821 25718-26065/com.video E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147479552)

Comment: it was working before i upgraded my target and max sdk to 28 before it was 25
@TejasPandya

Comment: @SyedFuzailByhaqi  have you checked your videourl . because target sdk has nothing to do with videoview

Comment: @SyedFuzailByhaqi `OnErrorListner()` please print the error

Comment: D/Player:: what: 1
D/Player:: extra: -2147479552

Comment: @SyedFuzailByhaqi error doesn't help much . but I would suggest you to test different videos also

Comment: @SyedFuzailByhaqi if it solved you issue you can accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
            //set the uri or path of the video to be played
            videoBackground.setVideoPath(enter your path);
            videoBackground.setVideoURI(enter your uri);

           videoBackground.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
             @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    videoViewRelative.start();
                }
            });
```